# How do you check if one of two string variables exists in a string using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

My code gives the following error:

> operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string'
>   and'string'.

```
var searchEN = @"WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER:\s*([0-9]+)";
var searchIE = @"UIMHIR AITHEANTAIS ÁIRITHINTE GRÉASÁIN:\s*([0-9]+)";
var match = Regex.Match(item.Body.Text, searchEN || searchIE);
```

Comment: Well what are you expecting the expression `searchEN || searchIE` to mean? Perhaps you meant to call `Regex.Match` on each of them, and take the `OR` of the result? That's very different.

Comment: never used c#, but what about `var match = Regex.Match(item.Body.Text, searchEN) || Regex.Match(item.Body.Text, searchIE)`?

Comment: @user2141046 That codes gives this error: _Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' and 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match'_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply combine the two patterns using the `|` operator like:

```
string pattern = @"WEB BOOKING ID NUMBER:\s*([0-9]+)|UIMHIR AITHEANTAIS ÁIRITHINTE GRÉASÁIN:\s*([0-9]+)";
var match = Regex.Match(item.Body.Text, pattern);
```

Check out the result at [this link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=WEB%20BOOKING%20ID%20NUMBER%3A%5Cs*%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%7CUIMHIR%20AITHEANTAIS%20%C3%81IRITHINTE%20GR%C3%89AS%C3%81IN%3A%5Cs*%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29&i=WEB%20BOOKING%20ID%20NUMBER%3A%20123%2C%20UIMHIR%20AITHEANTAIS%20%C3%81IRITHINTE%20GR%C3%89AS%C3%81IN%3A123).